# How can I query using a foreign key in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, mysqli

Right now I have a small database with two tables that look something like this:

```
    users table
    ====================
    id  name   status_id
    1   Bobby  3
    2   James  2
```

and

```
    statuses table
    =============
    id  value
    1   Waiting
    2   Approved
    3   Other
```

status_id is setup as a foreign key constraint to id from the statuses table. My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `status_id` = 2";
```

When I display `$row['status_id']` it outputs `2` but I would like it to display as `Approved` instead, what is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql.... However foreign keys are only supported on InnoDB, you cant do such thing in MyIsam.

Comment: @MiroMarkarian the relationship is setup properly and it is InnoDB, I just didn't understand how to use `JOIN` properly but it was answered below.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT u.*, s.*
FROM users u
    inner join statuses s on u.status_id = s.id
WHERE u.status_id = 2
```

Comment: +1 for answering the question and for using ANSI-compliant JOIN syntax.

Comment: I tried using this as my query, but when I echo `$row['status_id']` it still outputs `2`

Comment: @Riboflavin That is because you are asking for status_id, look at my answer. You need to ask for 'value' if that is indeed the name of the column in the statuses table.

Comment: @thatidiotguy ah of course, that works perfectly thank you! Excuse my noobness, I'm brand new to foreign keys.

Answer (score 6):

What you need is this

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
JOIN statuses ON statuses.id = users.status_id
WHERE `status_id` = 2";
```

and then you can refer to

```
$row['value'];
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be through joins:

```
select *
from User u join Status s on u.status_id = s.id;
```

(if you dont want the status-id at all, you can specify the columns that you do want in the select-clause.)

Answer (score 0):

Your users table does not have the value of approved in it. It is in your statuses table. When you request status_id you are going to get that value back from that query. You have to do a `JOIN ON status_id` to make this work out I think. Or do a second query.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)ing here:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users U, Statuses S
WHERE S.id=U.status_ID
AND status_id = 2;
```