# SQL Select on multiple tables to check if value exists in one table and not used in other

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
table1 (id,usedcode)
table2 (codeid,uniquecode)
```

I want to be able to check if a certain value exists in uniquecode of Table2, but is not already used in Table1

Comment: Great, and what have tried so far?

Comment: May I suggest looking into Left Joins?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I query using a foreign key in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483109/how-can-i-query-using-a-foreign-key-in-mysql)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to select if this condition holds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT uniquecode FROM Table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE usedcode = uniquecode
)
```

In English the query is saying, "Select all unique codes from table 2 that      don't exist in table 1 as a usedcode".

Answer (score 1):

Try using left join as below:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.uniquecode = t1.usedcode
WHERE t1.usedcode IS null
```