# Delete a row with relations with other tables

Tags: mysql

If I have the following tables:

```
Product
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | box  |
|  2 | car  |
|  3 | ball |
+----+------+

Color
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | red   |
|  2 | green |
|  3 | blue  |
+----+-------+

Size
+----+--------+
| id | number |
+----+--------+
|  1 |      1 |
|  2 |      5 |
|  3 |     10 |
+----+--------+

Color Options (#product | #color)
+---------+-------+
| product | color |
+---------+-------+
|       1 |     1 |
|       1 |     3 |
|       3 |     1 |
|       3 |     2 |
|       2 |     3 |
+---------+-------+

Size Options (#product | #size)
+---------+-------+
| product | color |
+---------+-------+
|       1 |     1 |
|       1 |     2 |
|       3 |     1 |
|       3 |     2 |
|       2 |     2 |
|       2 |     3 |
+---------+-------+
```

When I delete a product what is the best way to delete the relations it have with color and size? Do I need to do a delete in every table or there any automatic process?

Comment: i'd make a `deleteProduct($id)` kind of function that would run DELETE queries on all the tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set up proper **RELATIONSHIP** for your mysql?
You can refer to this question
[How to create relationships in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql) and [MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Comment: you have to add the ON DELETE CASCADE when referencing the foreign key so that in your case, it will delete automatically

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE SIZE_OPTIONS(PRODUCT REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID), COLOR REFERENCES COLOR_OPTIONS(COLOR) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

Use the same knind of the statement with COLOR_OPTIONS.

Comment: every time I use a FOREIGN KEY should I use ON DELETE CASCADE? didn't you mean: CREATE TABLE SIZE_OPTIONS(PRODUCT REFERENCES PRODUCT(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE);

Comment: If you want relationship to have cascading effect, use ON DELETE CASCADE. Not, if you do not want that

Answer (score -1):

INNER JOIN is an answer

```
DELETE
FROM Product p
  INNER JOIN Color_Options co
    ON co.product = p.id
  INNER JOIN Color c
    ON co.color = c.id
  INNER JOIN Size_Options so
    ON co.product = p.id
  INNER JOIN Size s
    ON so.color = s.id
```