# MySQL DELETE using relationships with different conditions

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

```
+--------+---------------------+--------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------------+------+--------+-------+
| UserID | email               | name   | surname    | password                                                     | place | birthDay   | male | female | admin |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------------+------+--------+-------+
|     10 | elo@elo.pl          | elo    | elo        | $2b$12$JPdUjCFv2mtoG3b2Dx0v1.D5089S4wUsg0aS21joLhlrzb1f4X3sW | stg   | 2000-12-09 |    1 |      0 |     1 |
|     11 | kacper@wp.pl        | kacper | kacper     | $2b$12$mlKWmIwdmj8Q0Py36H3m1O2REqYD9VBacmmk8jiogBIfrUmKy4XpG | stg   | 0000-00-00 |    1 |      0 |     0 |
|     12 | filip@galikowski.pl | filip  | galikowski | $2b$12$7cxOXVs/tHytGE/j0nA/s.wdxOherYlJf18F3EA/elvUblEN99pLy | stg   | 0000-00-00 |    1 |      0 |     0 |
|     13 | kacper@niemczyk.pl  | kacper | niemczyk   | $2b$12$YoSDXFc/t.jr5K8EFrY16OH8jom6kylCqvdFL7FfL2rdrO6hVzxCa | stg   | 0000-00-00 |    1 |      0 |     0 |
+--------+---------------------+--------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------------+------+--------+-------+

+--------+------------+
| UserID | FollowerID |
+--------+------------+
|     12 |         13 |
|     10 |         13 |
+--------+------------+
```

I need to delete a given row with the email of the observer and email of the observed person.

For example.

I got email: "kacper@niemczyk.pl" and "elo@elo.pl" and I have to remove these people from the follow table. In this example delete row with UserID = 10 and FollowerID = 13

I know that it is possible to find an ID via email and then delete it but I also know that it can be done faster with the help of relations but I do not know how.

Comment: You question doesn't make much sense? you can delete via the ID which is a pretty standard way or doing things? can you go into more detail about your other approach?

Comment: answer for your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335659/delete-a-row-with-relations-with-other-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as a reference:

```
create table users (id int, name varchar(10));
insert into users values (1, 'Kacper'),(2, 'Krzysztof'), (3, 'Kuba');
create table followers (userid int, followerid int);
insert into followers values (1, 2), (1, 3);
--now we want to delete from followers records, where Krzysztof follows Kacper
delete from followers
where exists (select 1 from users
              where id = followers.userid and name = 'Kacper')--followed user
  and exists (select 1 from users
              where id = followers.followerid and name = 'Krzysztof');--follower
```

**EDIT regarding comment**:

To add records to `followers` in simialir manner, use:

```
insert into followers
select u1.id, u2.id from users u1
cross join users u2
where u1.name = 'Kacper' --followed user
  and u2.name = 'Krzysztof' --follower
```

Comment: Thank for help! I almost understand the whole query, I only have to look at it a few times to be able to use it myself

Comment: Could you please help me with adding to the table in the same way? (exactly the same instead of removing but adds)

Comment: Thank you, it works! The problem is that in comparison to removal, I do not understand the action of adding ... Could you explain it to me theoretically?

Comment: You join the table `users` with itself, getting all combinations of users. Then you filter out on what users you want to add specifying their names (e-mails in your case) in `where` clause.

Comment: A little complicated but I will try to understand exactly in practice. Thank you very much for help!

Comment: Why not `delete from followers where userid = (select id from users where name = 'Kacper') and followerid = (select id from users where name = 'Krzysztof');`?

Comment: @JonHeggland It's generally recommended to use `exists` in such situation.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn Why?