# Yii - Can gii be used to create CRUD for a Model that joins tables through relations?

Tags: yii, gii

I'm planning on creating a model that joins some tables to be used in a CGridView.  Will the CRUD generated by gii work on this?  Specifically the ability to Create/Update.

I've already tried generating CRUD on a MYSQL view - which did not work right for Create/Update.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that MySql's ISAM does not support relations. However, if you create your tables with the [INNODB engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql), you can define foreign keys.

It is also supported by SQLite, however. The Yii blogs tutorial shows an [example](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.database) of defining relations at the database level.

In that case, Gii dutifully creates Models with the relations predefined (or better: taken from the database).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am just going to have to play around with it a bit to find out.  Just installed giix as well in hopes of having a bit more functionality.