# How to create relations in YII for 3 DB tables

Tags: php, yii

I have 3 DB tables tbl_categories, tbl_items, tbl_items_categories like this:

```
tbl_categories fields: id (category id - primary key), name (category's name)
tbl_items fields: id (item id - primary key), name (item name)
tbl_items_categories fields: id (primary key), item_id (id field value from tbl_items), category_id (id field value from tbl_category)
```

Please note that one item can be in multiple categories (tbl_items_categories is being used for this purpose)

I have created 3 models (in YII)  - categories, items, itemMultiCategories for these tables.

Can anyone please let me know how to create relations in YII for following purpose:

1. If I have an item id, I should be able to get all its category names (good to have category ids)
2. If I have category id, I should get all item names in that category (good to have item ids as well)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating relations in Yii, you are doing it in the database.
Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/260453/2651326).
After you created the relations, go into the gii (http://yourhost.com/?r=gii), and create all the models again. Don't forget to check the checkbox for relation creation.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a many to many relationship bridged by an associative table (tbl_items_categories).  This should be easily handled by Yii's many to many relational active record.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr

For instance, to have a relationship in your items model that gets you all categories, you could do something like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'categories' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'categories','tbl_items_categories(item_id, category_id)'),
    );
}
```

The foreign key, `tbl_items_categories(item_id, category_id)`, is just the name of your associative table with the table fields that will match your linked tables, in parentheses.  Your fields should be listed in order, such that the field that will link to the primary key of the current model is listed first.  My understanding is if you want to get items by category, the foreign key in the relationship in your category model will look like this: `tbl_items_categories(category_id, item_id)`.

**A note on your associative table:**

You might consider removing the "id" field, since the combination of item_id and category_id is probably unique.  Also, because the table only needs to be referenced in these relationship declarations, you probably don't need to set up a separate model for it.