# Send data to a table from another table with choosing one row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I develop a web based cab reservation system. I have a table called vehicle and `cab_reservation` table in mysql database. So i want to select one vehicle from vehicle table and pass it to `cab_reservation` table when user booking a cab. In Vehicle table primary key is vehicle number.

Comment: Maybe you can look at the concept of `relations` as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql Otherwise, a more precise question would be welcome: what do you mean by "pass it to". If you're using PHP, you could easily get the vehicle_id (I presume) and add it into your next MySQL query...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language you want to use. But as we have only information that you are using `MySQL`, you can use something like this

```sql
INSERT INTO cab_reservation (vehicle_number, other_columns, ... )
SELECT  v.vehicle_number, ...
FROM    vehicle v
WHERE   v.vehicle_number = ...;
```

I suppose `cab_reservation` has some sort of id as primary key and additional data.