# Implementing a IS-A relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I need help with an exercise; I have three entities: Employee(id, name) , Technician ( name, city , salary) and Medic ( id, hospital, room ) . Technician and medic are linked to Employee by a is a relationship. The problem is that I dont know how to implement the IS-A in SQL.

Comment: You may want to check this: [How to create relationships in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql)

Comment: Common please use Google or tell specific problem :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would create two new tables, each one for the 'a is a' relationship. For example: employee_technician (and employee_medic)

'employee_technician's Primary Key would consist of two columns: employee's PK and technician's PK.