# Want to get multiple rows into a single row for a user using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am looking for a solution for following:

[image]

Where I need a SQL query that get data for each user_id with all enrolment_value merged into a single row for the same user.

I am wondering if this is really possible or not.

I have tried Group by query but I get only 1 record not sure how to merge all the records for a user espacially under enrolment_value column.

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: What you're looking for is a JOIN and for that you need a relational table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260441/how-to-create-relationships-in-mysql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to *aggregate* all `enrolment_value` per `user_id` from MySQL, you can do so using aggregate functions like [`JSON_ARRAYAGG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) or [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat).

For example, given the following data sample on the `enrolments` table:

| id | user_id | enrolment_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `1` | `{"a": "value 1"}` |
| `2` | `2` | `{"a": "value 2"}` |
| `3` | `1` | `{"a": "value 3"}` |

When we use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` as follows:

```mysql
SELECT
    user_id,
 JSON_ARRAYAGG(enrolment_value) AS enrolment_values
FROM enrolments
GROUP BY user_id;
```

We get:

| user_id | enrolment_values |
| --- | --- |
| `1` | `[{"a": "value 1"},{"a": "value 3"}]` |
| `2` | `[{"a": "value 2"}]` |

Thanks to the `GROUP BY` clause, all rows with identical `user_id`s will be "squashed" into one row. But because we paired the clause to `JSON_ARRAYAGG`, all `enrolment_value`s of the rows that will be squashed, will be "encoded" into a JSON array.

Now, with all `enrolment_value`s of unique `user_id`s merged into one as JSON array, decoding said JSON should be pretty trivial to do in Laravel.

Comment: NEXT STEP, extract JSON to coulmns

However, I am having issues with JSON_EXTRACT on GROUP_CONCAT, getting following error: "The document root must not be followed by other values"
using following in SELECT:
JSON_EXTRACT(GROUP_CONCAT(`enrolment_value`), '$.schedule') AS 'schedule',

Comment: When I try  to use JSON_ARRAYAGG its showing me NULL responce but no error.

JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_ARRAYAGG(`enrolment_value`), '$.schedule') AS 'from_array'

The reason could be that SQL is escaping double qoutes on JSON_ARRAYAGG values, i.e.:

["{\"schedule\":\"25 Hours\",\"employment_service\":\"Disability Employment Service (DES)\"}"]

Any solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @MohsinA. You need to use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` with `JSON_EXTRACT()`, not `GROUP_CONCAT()`. Then, query like so: `JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_ARRAYAGG(enrolment_value), '$[*].schedule') AS from_array`. Hope this helps!